# Compare datetime to current datetime in mysql?

Tags: mysql

i'm currently working on compare both date and time to the current date and time in mysql but something not logic occurs, take a look on mysql statement

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE expiry_date_time > NOW()
```

i expect that as long as the expiry date and time is larger than NOW() so it's still active and not expire.
When i tested it with already non expired row it failed and when changing from ">" to "<" it works !!!

What's wrong with my code or logic ?!

**EDIT:-**
expiry_date_time is column of type DATETIME

sample date :-
[image]

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| id | expiry_date_time    | add_date_time       | is_active |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| 38 | 2014-10-09 02:17:29 | 2014-10-09 01:00:29 | ☺         |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

**Edit 2:-**

I discovered an error in my php code prevent outputting NOW() correctly, so the logic and query above work perfectly with no error

Comment: What's in `expiry_date_time`? Is it a `DateTime` column or a `varchar()`?

Comment: @MikeW it's column of type DATETIME

Comment: You need to post some sample data that illustrates your problem. I'd put money on MySQL having it right and you've misunderstood something.

Comment: @MikeW i updated the question with sample data image from mysql workbench

Comment: Try SELECT NOW(), expiry_date_time FROM table and see if data comparing is getting the right result

Comment: @LiKiaChiu nice idea when verifying results now = 2014-10-09 01:49:46 and expiry_date_time is 2014-10-09 02:17:29 which means that the expiry_date_time > NOW()

Comment: Then the SQL is correct, it will output all the data that expiry_date_time > NOW() no matter the is_active status.  Are you doing something else outside the SQL?

Comment: @LiKiaChiu thanks for reply , i discovered an error in my php code preventing NOW() from being printed correctly and problem solved.

Comment: @user1635227 Your problem has no more reason to stay open, don't forget to close the question

Comment: this query will always result you all the results.as now is changing each and every second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered an error in my php code prevent outputting NOW() correctly, so the logic and query above work perfectly with no error